# Express sessions does not persist across requests and set cookie in browser - in production (client and server hosted on separate urls)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, session-cookies

I am working on an e-commerce application using React (Vite) on the frontend, Node, MySQL, Sequelize, and Express with express-sessions and sequelize session store. While everything works locally, in production, I have found that my cookie is not stored in the browser and that my session does not persist when I am communicating between my client and server hosted on separate urls. I have been trying everything to resolve this for the past week with no success. I am not even sure if it is possible to fix at this point but would greatly appreciate any insight.

My backend relies heavily on express sessions to create a cookie and store the user id for authentication and fetch data for the logged in user on my various routes. My client-side code exists independently and communicates with the backend via fetch requests. Locally, I have all client side requests to /api set to proxy to the locally running express server as seen in my vite.config file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:3000/", // Replace with your backend server URL
      "/shop": "http://localhost:3000/",
    },
  },
});
```

When I hit the /api/user/login endpoint from the front end I am logged in and can see a new cookie set in the browser. I am able to refresh and maintain my logged in status across network requests.

However, in production I can no longer use the proxy. I have my frontend React app deployed to netlify and every fetch request it makes goes to the url for my server hosted on Heroku.

```
fetch("https://gentle-spire-83185-d5ea8d952a7d.herokuapp.com/api/user/login", {
  credentials: "include",
});
```

I can still log in and see that the login route console.logs the req.session with the cookie and my userId attached. I also see in the network tab that my login request does have a cookie attached in the response. However, I do not see any cookie set in the application tab, not in the Netlify site nor the server on Heroku. If I try to navigate to a different route that requires req.session.userId to be defined, I get an error for not being logged in. Similarly, when I refresh, I am back at the login page with no data saved on the session. So clearly the cookie is not being set and my userId is not being maintained on the session across network requests.

[Cookie showing in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzOSQ.png)

[Console after logging in (shows my userId on session)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAkx4.png)

But no cookie is showing up in the browser on the netlify site nor the heroku site hosting the backend:

My Express-session configuration:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://main--gorgeous-duckanoo-f2f18a.netlify.app",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// use the express session middleware providing options
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new SequelizeStore({
      db: sequelize,
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      path: "/",
      domain: "main--gorgeous-duckanoo-f2f18a.netlify.app",
    },
  })
);
```

Login route:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  // check db for matching username
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
    },
  });

  if (!existingUser) {
    return res.status(404).send({ error: "incorrect credentials" });
  }

  // compare password using instance method defined on user model
  if (existingUser.checkPassword(req.body.password, existingUser.password)) {
    // set and save logged in user on session object
    req.session.userId = existingUser.id;
    req.session.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
    });
    console.log(req.session);
    return res.status(200).send(req.session);
  }
  
  // if wrong password
  return res.status(404).send({ error: "incorrect credentials" });
});
```

Every fix I have seen has to do with changing the cookie settings which I have tried to no avail. I  do not get any errors related to cors or my server, it is just the lack of a cookie being set which I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

1. Proxy does not work in production, it only helps in development environment.
2. Cookies are not working because your client and server are hosted on separately.

**Solution:** You can host both front-end and backend together. Put the **build/dist** folder of react(vite) into the backend files then serve it using "**express.static**" method. Now you only have to host your backend. Hope this helps!